# javascript toggle class of child element inside clicked div chrome & Edge bug

Tags: javascript

i have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaroslav_cherednikov/0qsy6hjf/) example i built

this function

```
for (o = 0; o < buttons.length; o++){
   buttons[o].addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.target.childNodes[1].classList.toggle("clclp-dashbrd_frame-row-arrow-rotate");
   });
}
```

does not work properly in chrome and edge. but in firefox and iE11 it does work.

it appears that in chrome/edge when you click on the text of the row or the arrow itself, the arrow won't flip, while clicking between those works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only happens when you click directly on the `<i>` icon. In this case, the click event still fires, but `e.target` is the `<i>` instead of the `<button>` so your extremely fragile `e.target.childNodes[1]...` breaks.

You can fix this by using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

```
for (o = 0; o < buttons.length; o++){
   buttons[o].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.currentTarget.childNodes[1].classList.toggle("clclp-dashbrd_frame-row-arrow-rotate");
   })
}
```